# Mechanisms to enumerate resources of Azure

Tags: java, azure

I have a requirement where I need to periodically enumerate the resources of azure namely - VMs, Images, Instance types, Regions, Resource groups, storage, networks and so on.

The current approach I am thinking is to periodically make the Java SDK calls to list these resources and enumerate them into my local store. This can be done on a scheduled basis (say every 10 mins).

However, I was wondering if Azure provides any other mechanism to do this. For example, Is there a way to subscribe changes for say VMs and we get notified whenever there's a change in VM state (power off to power on, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such mechanism. There might be some events available in Event Grid, but generally speaking - no.

Comment: Yup. Azure Event grid provides these events with a small cost factor associated with them. I can explore that option. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just as @4c74356b41 said ,there is no any mechanism for monitoring changes in VMs.

You could use [Time Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function) in Azure Function or [Web Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs) to monitor your resources situation and send a reminder as a message.